# Design table driven equation driven parametric curves for sketches in Solidworks

Tags: solidworks

Do these exist?  I suspect they don't..  Equation driven parametric curves for sketches yes, but not with their parameters set by design  table.. The closest I'll be able to get, I think, is what I'm currently doing, which is using a spline (partially parametric..) and controlling -it's- input via design table..

Comment: I came across a system of equations someone published a while ago for creating gear teeth profiles (involute curves) that were essentially splines. Don't remember the link or title of the page anymore unfortunately. But I imagine once you derive the equations for the points you need you should be able to incorporate them into a design table.

Comment: of course this would work? Just put global variables in your equation, and vary them with the table?

Comment: @JonathanRSwift ah?  global variables?   ..will have to check those puppies out..  awesome!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what jko was referring to.

https://thebloughs.net/involute-gear-generation-in-solidworks/

This is just background information for the equations used in the first link.

[https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Curves/Involute/#:~:text=Involute%20of%20a%20Circle%20Parametric%20Cartesian%20equation%3A%20x,t%20cos%20%28t%29%29%20x%20%3Da%28cos%28t%29%2Btsin%28t%29%29%2Cy%20%3D%20a%28sin%28t%29%E2%88%92%20tcos%28t%29%29](https://mathshistory.st-andrews.ac.uk/Curves/Involute/#:%7E:text=Involute%20of%20a%20Circle%20Parametric%20Cartesian%20equation%3A%20x,t%20cos%20%28t%29%29%20x%20%3Da%28cos%28t%29%2Btsin%28t%29%29%2Cy%20%3D%20a%28sin%28t%29%E2%88%92%20tcos%28t%29%29)